# Vector convolution

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

after some calculations on some problem I got de following formula
$$
M(\mathbf{k}) = \int d^3q \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{q}f(\vert\mathbf{q} \vert) f(\vert \mathbf{k} - \mathbf{q} \vert)
$$
where $f$ is a known analytical function. How can I evaluate his numerically for a given $\mathbf{k}$? His os some kind of vectorial convolution.

Comment: You can make the simplification $$M(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{|\mathbf{k}|^2}{2} \int d^3\mathbf{q} f(|\mathbf{q}|)f(|\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{q}|)$$

Comment: I did´n see that, thanks. My main problem is the evaluation of the angular part of this integral. By brute force I must make a grid ar the coordinates $q$, $\theta_q$ and $\phi_q$ bust computationally I is awful.